# PySide.QtGui.QDialog issue

Tags: python, pyside

I want to draw a frame around my borderless dialog while it gets resized interactively but it seems like `QDialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)` and `QWidget.resizeEvent` doen't work well together. The dialog can't be resized interactively, is this a known problem ?

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setGeometry(x,y,250,300)    
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(self.rect())
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Plain)
        etc...

    def resizeEvent( self, event ):
        r = self.rect()
        s = event.size()
        self.frame.setGeometry( r.x(), r.y(), s.width(), s.height() )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you override the `resizeEvent` without passing it on, this seems to break the functionality of the generated size grip.

The simplest solution would be to call:

```
    super(MyDialog, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

in your event handler. Another option is to add your own `QResizeGrip` to your frame:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        # [...]
        self.frame.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.sizeGrip = QtGui.QSizeGrip(self.frame)
        self.frame.layout().addWidget(self.sizeGrip, 0,
                QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.setStyleSheet("QSizeGrip {background-color: #202020}") # make it visible
        # [...]
```

This has the advantage that you can arrange the size grip freely.